# i want to use bcc or cc function in this mail function?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

i want to use bcc or cc function in this mail function?

**Here My Mail Function**

```
 <?php
//SENDS EMAIL THAT TELLS THE USER TO ACTIVATE THE ACCOUNT
$activation = 'activation.php?key='.$key;
$your_email = 'non-reply@mydomain.pk'; //CHANGE TO YOUR SETTINGS
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; //YOUR DOMAIN AND EXTENSION
$to  = $email;
$subject = 'MyDomain Activate Account';
$message .='<img src="http://mydomain.com/images/securedownload.jpg"/>';
$message = 'Welcome,<br/> '.$_POST['username'].'. You must activate your account via   this       message to log in. Click the following link to do so:   http://'.$domain.'/'.$activation;
$headers = 'From: Mydomain<'.$your_email.'@'.$domain.'>\r\n'; //MODIFY TO YOUR SETTINGS
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html\r\n';
mail($to, $subject, $message,  $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add to the to and headers part of the mail.

**For TO part**

```
$to = "to@to.com, cc@cc.com"
```

**For HEADERS part**

```
$headers .= "To: To Name <to@to.com>\n";
$headers .= "CC: CC Name <cc@cc.com>\n";
$headers .= "BCC: BCC Name <bcc@bcc.com>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple, just sharing if anyone gets help from here:

```
//......
//...Other setting goes here....

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: My Name <myemail@example.com>'. "\r\n";
//Multiple CC can be added, if we need (comma separated);
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss1@example.com, myboss2@example.com' . "\r\n";
//Multiple BCC, same as CC above;
$headers .= 'Bcc: myboss3@example.com, myboss4@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message,  $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Bcc/CC in your Code

```
<?php
//SENDS EMAIL THAT TELLS THE USER TO ACTIVATE THE ACCOUNT
$activation = 'activation.php?key='.$key;
$your_email = 'non-reply@mydomain.pk'; //CHANGE TO YOUR SETTINGS
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; //YOUR DOMAIN AND EXTENSION
$to  = $email;
$subject = 'MyDomain Activate Account';
$message .='<img src="http://mydomain.com/images/securedownload.jpg"/>';
$message = 'Welcome,<br/> '.$_POST['username'].'. You must activate your account via   this       message to log in. Click the following link to do so:   http://'.$domain.'/'.$activation;
$headers = 'From: Mydomain<'.$your_email.'@'.$domain.'>\r\n'; //MODIFY TO YOUR SETTINGS
$headers .=  "BCC: email@domain.com;\r\n"
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html\r\n';
mail($to, $subject, $message,  $headers);
?>
```

Comment: $headers .= "BCC: MyDomain Order Copy <my@domain.com>\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

$headers .= "From: myDomain<'.$your_email.'@'.$domain.'>\r\n" .  
       //"Reply-To: $from \r\n" .  
       "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

Comment: let me try this one $headers .=  "BCC: email@domain.com;\r\n" i think it will be work